# SQLite Record is populated but Empty w/ C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am creating an app that allows you to schedule college terms.
My main form displays terms and their properties correctly.
If a user clicks a term, it opens a new window and loads classes in the term.
The list on Add Term page displays one item in its  as expected (added in Main Page), but its properties are all blank.

On Appearing in MainForm:

```
  protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        await _connection.CreateTableAsync<Term>();
        await _connection.CreateTableAsync<Class>();
        await _connection.CreateTableAsync<Assessment>();

        var termLists = await _connection.Table<Term>().ToListAsync();

        // Seed data if there are no Terms
        if (!termLists.Any())
        {
            // Seed Data
            var newTerm = new Term();
            newTerm.Title = "Term 1";
            newTerm.Start = DateTime.Now;
            newTerm.End = DateTime.Now;
            await _connection.InsertAsync(newTerm);
            termLists.Add(newTerm);

            var newCourse = new Class();
            newCourse.classTitle = "Capstone";
            newCourse.start = new DateTime(2019, 11, 12);
            newCourse.end = new DateTime(2019, 12, 18);
            newCourse.status = "Completed";
            newCourse.instructorName = "John Smith";
            newCourse.instructorPhone = "123-455-7789";
            newCourse.instructorEmail = "John.Smith@wgu.edu";
            newCourse.courseNotes = "Notes about the course";
            newCourse.term = newTerm.TermID;
            await _connection.InsertAsync(newCourse);

            Assessment newObjectiveAssessment = new Assessment();
            newObjectiveAssessment.title = "Test 1";
            newObjectiveAssessment.start = new DateTime(2019, 11, 18);
            newObjectiveAssessment.end = new DateTime(2019, 11, 21);
            newObjectiveAssessment.ClassID = newCourse.classID;
            newObjectiveAssessment.Assessments = "Objective";
            await _connection.InsertAsync(newObjectiveAssessment);

        }


        var courseList = await _connection.Table<Class>().ToListAsync();
        var assessmentList = await _connection.Table<Assessment>().ToListAsync();

        termList.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Term>(termLists);
        studentTerms = termLists;

        base.OnAppearing();
    }
```

Event Handler for user clicking term:

```
   async private void termList_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int selectionIndex = e.SelectedItemIndex;

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new AddTerm(studentTerms[selectionIndex]));
    }
```

On Appearing in Add Term:

```
 protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        await _connection.CreateTableAsync<Class>();

        if (term != null)
        {
            var courseList = await _connection.QueryAsync<Class>($"SELECT * FROM Class WHERE term = '{term.TermID}'");
            _courses = new ObservableCollection<Class>(courseList);
            classList.ItemsSource = _courses;
            //DisplayAlert("Course Name", courseList[0].classTitle, "cancel");
        }
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
```

Edit:
I have examined courselist as requested and everything is null except for the ID of the course and the ID of the term.

Edit2: Pretty sure I figured out the problem. In my implementation of my Class object, I did not add {get;set;} to the fields that didn't populate.

Comment: you need to figure out if the data is actually missing, or if the UI is just not displaying the data correctly. Use the debugger to examine `courseList` after you load the data to figure out which it is.

Comment: The data is actually missing. I examined the output, and the only valid data points are the IDs

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I didn't add {get;set;} to my properties within my class object.

Comment: In essense you had fields, not properties.